# How to remove this ' + ' SIGN from visual studio 2017 project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In this image you can see differents kind of files but some files like favicon , global , pakcages have ' + ' SIGN . so how can i remove this ' + ' SIGN ??

[image: solution tree-view]

Comment: That imagen are from the source control. If you don't want it to be show, Just disconnect from git or team foundation.

Answer (score 6):

That just shows they've been added to the project since the last commit. If you commit them to source control, the + will vanish.

If you modify a file, there'll be a green tick next to icon instead.

Unmodified files have a small blue padlock.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the '+' sign from your project, you need to right click and undo check out. That's the choice you need to make.